# HTML canvas image is not showing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This is the code:

```
<head>
    <title>Canvas</title>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="c" width="200" height="200">
    </canvas>

    <script>
        var c = document.querySelector("#c");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

        var image = new Image();

        image.onLoad = function() {
            console.log("Loaded Image");
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        };

        image.src = "fry_fixed.jpg";
    </script>
</body>
```

Canvas is getting created.
Image is not appearing.
I tried to debug it and found that the onLoad function is not working.
I can ensure you that image is in the same folder and the image name is correct.
But i still can't figure out why the code is not working!!

Comment: Try `image.addEventListener('load', function(){ ... }, false)` instead of `onLoad`, and if you use `onLoad`, then use the correct `onload` - non-capitalised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

case matters, it's `onload`, all lowercase, not `onLoad`

```
image.onload = function() {...
```

or the more modern `addEventListener`

```
image.addEventListener('load', function() {...}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `onload` instead of `onLoad`. Or even better, use an event listener!

```js
var c = document.querySelector("#c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var image = new Image();

// Better use addEventListener, to be honest.
// image.onload = function() {
//   ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
// };

image.addEventListener('load', function(){
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
}, false)

image.src = "http://placehold.it/200x200";
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: "Or even better, use an event listener" ...what do you think `onload` is?

Comment: @Pamblam congrats for a sarcastic comment, but `addEventListener` is a safer and better way to listen for events, as well as being more versatile. Better learn to good stuff first.

Comment: please tell me how your method is not exactly the same?

Comment: if youre going to say it's better, tell us why it's better.

Comment: @Pamblam https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Why_use_addEventListener - Get with the times.

Comment: This is the result of careless reading. None of those benefits apply in this case. As a general rule, simpler is better. You don't need and are not using any of the extra benefits addEventHandler here. In this case, they are exactly the same, therefor the shorter one is better.